# Pagination in timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I am using Timber, and currently trying to get pagination working as per the [Timber docs](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/#nav), though so far, without success. Below is my custom archive php file:

```
global $paged;
if (!isset($paged) || !$paged){
    $paged = 1;
}
$context = Timber::get_context();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$context['subCatItems'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args);

Timber::render('archive-product.twig', $context);
```

And my corresponding Twig file:

```
<div class="l-container vert-push--small vert-push--adult--medium">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="c-std">{{ post.title }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="tool-pagination c-std">
    {% if posts.pagination.prev %}
        <a href="{{posts.pagination.prev.link}}" class="prev {{posts.pagination.prev.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Prev</a>
    {% endif %}
    <ul class="pages">
        {% for page in posts.pagination.pages %}
            <li>
                {% if page.link %}
                    <a href="{{page.link}}" class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% if posts.pagination.next %}
        <a href="{{posts.pagination.next.link}}" class="next {{posts.pagination.next.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The main issue at the moment is that `posts_per_page` seems to do nothing, and I am just getting all the posts rendering on the page (about 20 currently), when there should be only 2 with the pagination (which isn't currently showing. Any ideas?

Comment: I see that you add the query that should only contain 2 posts to `subCatItems` in the context. However, in the Twig file, you’re not using `subCatItems` anywhere. Instead, you’re generating the pagination for `posts`, which is set through `$context = Timber::get_context()` in your PHP file, and which is using the default query for your archive page.

Comment: Try `'numberposts'   => 2` instead of `post_per_page`

Comment: @Mina You sure? Thought `numberposts` was deprecated a while back in favour of the reworked `posts_per_page`..

Comment: @wickywills - That's good to know! Though they say `'numberposts' and 'posts_per_page' can be used interchangeably.` here  https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have the privilege to comment so I have to post this way.

Your code shows that you render 'archive-product.twig' and query your 'product' post type so you you should try the approach of using the active query according to the docs you linked to. Did you try that already?

**Edit**

A while after posting this I needed to build an implementation of a timber twig pagination - and failed in the beginning because the item count was different to the number of posts per page as defined in WP backend. I thought to add a tiny bit of information that could be useful to somebody..

So in case you need a different number of posts in you custom posttype archive having pagination try this:

In your controller or you archive file:

```
global $paged;
if (!isset($paged) || !$paged){
    $paged = 1;
}

$args_cp = array(
    'post_type' => 'HERE_YOUR_CUSTOM_POSTTYPE_NAME',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args_cp);
```

Additionally you need this in your function.php as long as the number of
posts per page is not the same like in the WP backend:

```
function cpt_archive_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    // for cpt or any post type main archive
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'HERE_YOUR_CUSTOM_POSTTYPE_NAME' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );   // number has to be the same like in your query / 'posts_per_page'
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_archive_posts_per_page' );
```

If you get a 404 on page 2 try Timber Twigs authors suggestion:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/

Section: ***Pagination with pre_get_posts***

```
function my_home_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'movie', 'post' ));
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_query' );
```

Adjust values to your needs of course :)

Comment: Apologies for not accepting sooner. I reworked my code to take advantage of the active query, and things started working!

Comment: Ah that is nice to hear! Thanks for comming back and accepting the answer!